# How to get all MAC address and port number of IP camera on a LAN network using C++?

Tags: c++, ip-camera

I have many IP cameras on the same LAN network. I want to get MAC address and port number of each camera,  although I don't know ip address of them. Furthermore, if the ip and port of a camera is changed, how to detect it?

I've also searched on internet about this problem. Most of people responded using some of the Window functions such as SendARP () or using command line "arp -a". But if do it, then get all MAC address of the LAN network that regardless of the camera's or the computer's.

Please help me!

Comment: I think, that it need no real programming to solve you problem and belongs to serverfault.

Comment: there are a number of freeware/shareware apps that are specifically written to help with this, including http://www.angryip.org/w/Home & http://10base-t.com/iphone-ipod-software/camscan/

Answer (score 2):

I would start with a port scanner such as nmap and look for information that will identify your IP cameras.

```
nmap -A -T4 192.168.0.0/24
```

If all of your cameras are the same, you may be able to detect them by the OS information returned.

You might also be able to do a banner grab to determine the port:

```
nmap -sV --script=banner 192.168.0.0/24
```

Use C++ to parse the nmap output.  Change the network address range to fit your network.

Answer (score 1):

Do your IP cameras broadcast any identifying information, e.g with mDNS packets? Maybe you can catch these broadcasts.  Google for "mDNS" or "Zeroconf".

Answer (score 1):

Are all of the cameras you are looking for made by the same company?  If so, the MAC addresses may all share a common prefix that was assigned to that company, or do they support HTTP or some other protocol you could use to probe the camera to identify it as well?

If they don't share similar MAC addresses, you can still use other methods to find all the cameras.

One way I might approach the problem:

```
For each IP address in your network range {
    Send ARP request for IP address

    If ARP response received {
       Check MAC address of ARP response

       If MAC address matches camera MFR {
           // Add to list
       } else {
           // Probe IP address for device specific webpage or service
           If probe matches { 
               // Add to list
           }
       }
    }
}
```

You may find that the cameras support some `SNMP` commands that you could use as an identifying factor.  In the worst case, you could send an `HTTP` packet to the IP address and see if the host responds with the webpage for the camera assuming each one has an embedded web server.  Chances are, there is at least one protocol you could use to identify the cameras out of all of your network devices.

Comment: Thanks, but I assume that there is an ip camera with the IP is different subnet mask from my PC, then how can I do with the loop "For each IP address in your network range"? 
And in your above code you have mentioned " If MAC address matches camera MFR ". I dont know what is MFR, can you explain to me.
Many thanks!

Comment: So your PC is on a different network than the cameras?  In that case, "your ip range" would just be a range you would manually enter that is really the network range where the cameras are.  By `MFR`, I just mean manufacturer.  Companies have to get assigned ranges of MAC addresses, so using a tool like [this](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/) you can check who controls a MAC address.  Chances are, if the cameras are all made by the same manufacturer, the beginning of their MAC addresses are all the same.  Does that help?